# Joomla 2.5 mootools ajax - Send parameters to component

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

I have been searching for hours now for a solution to this issue. I have a standard component with a controller thus:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
jimport( 'joomla.environment.request' );

class GetajaxController extends JController
{
  function test()   
   {
       $jinput = new JInput();
       $myvar = $jinput->getVar('eventname');
       print_r($_REQUEST);
       $a = $_GET['eventname'];
       $event = JRequest::getVar( 'eventname' ) ;
       $client = JRequest::getVar( 'client' ) ;   
       echo "CLIENT:".$client." EVENT:".$event."*".$myvar;
   }
}
```

(I have been trying multiple solutions which is why there is extra nonsense in there but the pertinent code is still there)

I call it from a custom module thusly:

```
$urlA = "index.php?option=com_getajax&task=test&format=raw";
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration("

    function runButton() {

       var data = 'eventname=aName&client=aClient';
       var url='$urlA';
       var request = new Request({
       url: url,
       data: data,
       method:'post',
       onSuccess: function(responseText){
         document.getElementById('xml_result').innerHTML=responseText;
       }
       }).post('eventname=foo&client=baR'); // ORIGINALLY HAD IT AS JUST .post()
       request.setHeader('eventname', 'sdfsdfsdf'); // ADDED
   }
");
```

The response back contains only the hard coded "CLIENT: ... EVENT" minus the variables. In other words, I do get a response and the ajax/jquery part of the whole thing is working fine, just I cannot seem for the life of me to successfully send the parameters to the component. (or at least, retrieve them in the component)

I've firebugged it and they are not in the response. I've even harded coded the url and used a simple $_GET in the controller with no success;

```
$urlA = "index.php?option=com_getajax&task=test&format=raw&event=foo&client=bar";
```

I have tried it with and without sef urls. And you can see from the controller that I've tried various methods to capture the passed params. I've also tried both 'get' and 'post'.

I have tried all the commonly posted solutions btw, so I'm figuring this has something to do with joomla stipping url parameters out in some obscure way that only the developers mother could appreciate.

- In firebug, there is an 'x' parameter showing up that I'm not sending that appears to be empty. Don't know if that's important or not.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this useful, I basically needed to parse it down to basics to get it to work.

This involved much trial and error though, and I don't claim to understand all of it exactly yet.

Controller:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

// need to get various libraries first for joomla specific controls

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.controller' );
jimport( 'joomla.environment.request' );

// we extend JController 

class GetajaxController extends JController {

  // the 'test' function will be a 'task' we can call in the url by the name 'test' 
  // (we can have many by simple defining new functions within our JController class)

    function test() {

        $app =& JFactory::getApplication();

        // get vars posted from module

        $foo = JRequest::getVar('aVar');
        $bar = JRequest::getVar('bVar');
        $result = doSomethingWithThem($foo,$bar);

        // encode result and send back. 
        // (using json encoding allows us multiple return variables. not used here.) 

        if($result) echo json_encode(array('test' => $result));

        // need to flush and close to prevent anything else but our data going back

        $app->close();
        return;
    }
}

// helper functions can be in the controller but not in the JController class

function doSomethingWithThem($foo,$bar) {
   return $foo . $bar;
}
```

Module:

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);

// bring in mootools (which I'm not convinced is needed here, but it works so...)

JHTML::_( 'behavior.mootools' );
JHtml::_( 'behavior.framework', true );

// add jscript to rendered page

$document->addScriptDeclaration("

   // add a function to an element event (a button in this case)
   jQuery('#btgetajax').live('click', function() {

      var aVar = "Something";
      var bVar = "Something else";

      // actually call the ajax component. notice the task=test. 
      // format=raw further asks the component to only return our data

      var url='index.php?option=com_getajax&task=test&format=raw';

      // json encode the data we're sending to the controller

      var dat = {'aVar':aVar, 'bVar':bVar};

      // send it via ajax

      jQuery.ajax({

         url: url,
         method: 'post',
         data: dat,
         dataType:'json',
         success: function(data) {
            alert(data.test);
         },
         error:function(xhr, status, data) {
            alert(status);
         }

      });
   });
");
```